# Get distance (horizontal distance i.e-left border to right - in pixels) between multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to get the exact distance between :

1. `#main` div left border to first div with `class="b"`
2. between first div with class="b" to second div with class = "b"

Note that the divs can be randomly placed and divs can be fixed positions, so there can be gaps between two divs. Calculations like width of all the number of divs with `class= a` wont be a solution in that case.

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

What I tried is this:

```
    $(".main").children(".a").each(function() {
        $(this).nextUntil(".b").length  /* basically this width I need I guess */
        console.log($(this).siblings(".b").prev(".a").html());
        var diff  = $(this).offset().top - $(this).nextUntil(".b").offset().top
        // here both values are same  so result is zero        
console.log('diff' + diff);   
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'distance'? Pixels between `left` positions? Pixels between `left` and `top`? Difference between indexes in the parent? More detail and a working example would really help here.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : yes sir ,I mean the horizontal difference in pixels

Comment: `var diff  = $(this).offset().top - $(this).nextUntil(".b").offset().top;` You missed another `.offset()` in your code

Comment: @YoYo: Does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @ParagBhayani : So using your code how to calculate between 2nd div (class=b) and 6th div (class = b)

Comment: @yoyo : in my example I am getting all class=b elements in elements variable, so distance between 2nd and 6th div will be distance[1], distance between parent 2nd would be distance[0] ... and onwards

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use offsetTop property of the DOM element.

code should be,

```
$(".main b")[0].offsetTop
```

or pure jQuery would look like

```
$(".main b").offset().top // This will return top offset of the first selector matching element
```

Now to get distance between consecutive divs, you can write a simple for loop over $(".main b") elements

```js
var elements = $(".main .b");
var offsets = []; // Array which saves offsets of elements
var distance = []; // Array which saves distance between each elements
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  var offset = $(elements[i]).offset().top;
  offsets.push(offset);
  if (i == 0) {
    distance.push(offset);
  } else {
    distance.push(offset - distance[i - 1]);
  }
}

console.log(offsets);
console.log(distance);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="a">some</div>
  <div class="b">some</div>
  <div class="a">some</div>
  <div class="a">some</div>
  <div class="a">some</div>
  <div class="b">some</div>
  <div class="a">some</div>
  <div class="a">some</div>
  <div class="b">some</div>
</div>
```

Also [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7t6xwnxb/)

Comment: it gives NAN  for distance[1]

Comment: @YoYo: Yah there are some small typos, corrected it see the answer

Comment: @YoYo : See now ;)

Comment: Actually I implemented Something else since your code was not working for me, Thanks though. I may use it later . I will definitly upvote your answer .